# Efficient plotting library for web applications

Tags: web-applications, plot

I am looking for a plotting library that can be used in web applications (point and line plots are must - antyhing else is a bonus).

It might be either server-side (Python) or client-side. The more interactive graphs are the better.

I have found some solutions of course, but none of them are good enough for volume of datasets we use. My last try was flot but it crashed browser for 28k datapoints.

Can you point some plotting solutions which mets my requirements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those are interested, finally I've choosen [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/). (It is server-side, python-based solution)